# How to conditionally prevent validation on ContentPart field in Orchard CMS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

In a `ContentPart` some of fields defined by `[Required]` attribute. but in some situations I don't want validate them.

For example in the `ContentPart` i have a Boolean field which named `DoNotValidate`, and when its value assigned with `True` I want to prevent the requirement validation on fields and does not take any requirement error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have required fields you can use another tool to check fields for example:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (Name == "Adam")
            {
                yield return
                    new ValidationResult("Nie podales imienia", new[] { "Name" });
            }
        }
```

Properites:

```
public string Name {get; set;}
```

In HTML(MVC3):

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

If you using method GET you can use this:

```
[HttpGet]
[CustomAuthorize]
[GroupRequired]
[RoleRequired(RoleEnum.Edit)]
```

If it`s not this what you want please specify your problem much more clear